# Laravel collection with multiple date filter with or operator

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, where-clause, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to filter several items from a **Collection** in Laravel 5.7. The items have a startdate and an (optional) enddate.

The filter i'm trying to create is the following.

`startdate <= now()` **AND**

**(** `enddate >= now()` **OR** `enddate = ''` **OR** `enddate = NULL` **)**

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
$this->items->where([  
  ['startdate', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))],
  ['enddate', '>=', date('Y-m-d')]
])->orWhere([
  ['startdate', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))],
  ['enddate', '=', '']
])->orWhere([
  ['startdate', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))],
  ['enddate', '=', null]
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More cleaner way would be using closure like this:

```
$this->items->where('startdate', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))
            ->where(function($q) {
                 $q->where('enddate', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))
                   ->orWhere('enddate', '')
                   ->orWhereNull('enddate');
             });
```

And probably as suggested in comment you should in fact use `items()` instead of `items` because using `items` you probably get elements from database instead of adding constraints to database query before.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i've tried it, but getting the following error: 
`explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given`

Comment: @Erik-Jan Are you sure problem is in this part of code? Also the question is what type of collection are you using - shouldn't yo use `$this->items()` instead of `$this->items` ?

Comment: Thanks, that triggered me trying it with (). I add the solution down below.

Comment: @Erik-Jan You shouldn't add your solution where I've already presented solution and added comment with additional hint.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marcin Nabialek i've got the solution.

I've had to use `$this->items()` instead of `$this->items` and had to append it with the `->get()` function.

The result:

```
$this->items()->where('startdate', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))
              ->where(function($q) {
                  $q->where('enddate', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))
                    ->orWhere('enddate', '')
                    ->orWhereNull('enddate');
              })->get();
```